# Delete a file inside multiple ZIP archives on the OS X command line

Tags: macos, bash, unix, zip

I'm trying to delete files with specific extensions from multiple zip archives.

For example I want to delete all .html files contained in the zip archives in the current path so I have tried this:
    `zip -d *.zip '*.html'`

This works for the first zip found but does not proceed further. Any suggestions in how to do this on OSX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `*.zip` will expand to all ZIP files before it's passed to the `zip` command.

Do this instead, with a simple loop:

```
for f in *.zip; do zip -d "$f" '*.html'; done
```

If you have Zsh, this kind of loop is a little shorter:

```
for f (*.zip) zip -d "$f" '*.html'
```

If you want to recurse into subfolders, with standard OS X tools, use `find`:

```
find /path/to/files -type f -name '*.zip' -exec zip -d {} '*.html' \;
```